# How to create switch the layers option using geoserver?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I did create some maps with three layers using layer groups with the help of some tutorials but i dint get the switching options like others.

How to get that + mark locates in the right top corner of the map and those switching options?? any corrections in the coding or do i have to do anything in the geoserver to get that option??

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>OpenLayers map preview</title>
        <!-- Import OL CSS, auto import does not work with our minified OL.js build -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/openlayers/theme/default/style.css"/>
        <!-- Basic CSS definitions -->
        <style type="text/css">
            /* General settings */
            body {
                font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size: small;
            }
            /* Toolbar styles */
            #toolbar {
                position: relative;
                padding-bottom: 0.5em;
                display: none;
            }

            #toolbar ul {
                list-style: none;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }

            #toolbar ul li {
                float: left;
                padding-right: 1em;
                padding-bottom: 0.5em;
            }

            #toolbar ul li a {
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: smaller;
                vertical-align: middle;
                color: black;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            #toolbar ul li a:hover {
                text-decoration: underline;
            }

            #toolbar ul li * {
                vertical-align: middle;
            }
            /* The map and the location bar */
            #map {
                clear: both;
                position: relative;
                width: 720px;
                height: 500px;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }

            #wrapper {
                width: 512px;
            }

            #location {
                float: right;
            }

            #options {
                position: absolute;
                left: 13px;
                top: 7px;
                z-index: 3000;
            }
            /* Styles used by the default GetFeatureInfo output, added to make IE happy */
            table.featureInfo, table.featureInfo td, table.featureInfo th {
                border: 1px solid #ddd;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                font-size: 90%;
                padding: .2em .1em;
            }

            table.featureInfo th {
                padding: .2em .2em;
                font-weight: bold;
                background: #eee;
            }

            table.featureInfo td {
                background: #fff;
            }

            table.featureInfo tr.odd td {
                background: #eee;
            }

            table.featureInfo caption {
                text-align: left;
                font-size: 100%;
                font-weight: bold;
                padding: .2em .2em;
            }
        </style>
        <!-- Import OpenLayers, reduced, wms read only version -->
        <script src="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/openlayers/OpenLayers.js" type="text/javascript">
        </script>
        <script defer="defer" type="text/javascript">
            var map;
            var untiled;
            var tiled;
            var pureCoverage = false;
            // pink tile avoidance
            OpenLayers.IMAGE_RELOAD_ATTEMPTS = 10;
            // make OL compute scale according to WMS spec
            OpenLayers.DOTS_PER_INCH = 25.4 / 0.28;

            function init(){
                // if this is just a coverage or a group of them, disable a few items,
                // and default to jpeg format
                format = 'image/png';
                if(pureCoverage) {
                    document.getElementById('filterType').disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById('filter').disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById('antialiasSelector').disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById('updateFilterButton').disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById('resetFilterButton').disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById('jpeg').selected = true;
                    format = "image/jpeg";
                }

                var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(
                    220854.36902639153, 1915133.4535498584,
                    239999.53723996147, 1932742.5638200312
                );
                var options = {
                    controls: [],
                    maxExtent: bounds,
                    maxResolution: 74.78581333425757,
                    projection: "EPSG:32644",
                    units: 'm'
                };
                map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', options);

                // setup tiled layer
                tiled = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                    "Geoserver layers - Tiled", "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/GHMC/wms",
                    {
                        LAYERS: 'bunny',
                        STYLES: '',
                        format: format
                    },
                    {
                        buffer: 0,
                        displayOutsideMaxExtent: true,
                        isBaseLayer: true,
                        yx : {'EPSG:32644' : false}
                    } 
                );

                // setup single tiled layer
                untiled = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                    "Geoserver layers - Untiled", "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/GHMC/wms",
                    {
                        LAYERS: 'bunny',
                        STYLES: '',
                        format: format
                    },
                    {
                       singleTile: true, 
                       ratio: 1, 
                       isBaseLayer: true,
                       yx : {'EPSG:32644' : false}
                    } 
                );

                map.addLayers([untiled, tiled]);
                // build up all controls
                map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar({
                    position: new OpenLayers.Pixel(2, 15)
                }));
                map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation());
                map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Scale($('scale')));
                map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition({element: $('location')}));
                map.zoomToExtent(bounds);

                // wire up the option button
                var options = document.getElementById("options");
                options.onclick = toggleControlPanel;

                // support GetFeatureInfo
                map.events.register('click', map, function (e) {
                    document.getElementById('nodelist').innerHTML = "Loading... please wait...";
                    var params = {
                        REQUEST: "GetFeatureInfo",
                        EXCEPTIONS: "application/vnd.ogc.se_xml",
                        BBOX: map.getExtent().toBBOX(),
                        SERVICE: "WMS",
                        INFO_FORMAT: 'text/html',
                        QUERY_LAYERS: map.layers[0].params.LAYERS,
                        FEATURE_COUNT: 50,
                        Layers: 'bunny',
                        WIDTH: map.size.w,
                        HEIGHT: map.size.h,
                        format: format,
                        styles: map.layers[0].params.STYLES,
                        srs: map.layers[0].params.SRS};

                    // handle the wms 1.3 vs wms 1.1 madness
                    if(map.layers[0].params.VERSION == "1.3.0") {
                        params.version = "1.3.0";
                        params.j = parseInt(e.xy.x);
                        params.i = parseInt(e.xy.y);
                    } else {
                        params.version = "1.1.1";
                        params.x = parseInt(e.xy.x);
                        params.y = parseInt(e.xy.y);
                    }

                    // merge filters
                    if(map.layers[0].params.CQL_FILTER != null) {
                        params.cql_filter = map.layers[0].params.CQL_FILTER;
                    } 
                    if(map.layers[0].params.FILTER != null) {
                        params.filter = map.layers[0].params.FILTER;
                    }
                    if(map.layers[0].params.FEATUREID) {
                        params.featureid = map.layers[0].params.FEATUREID;
                    }
                    OpenLayers.loadURL("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/GHMC/wms", params, this, setHTML, setHTML);
                    OpenLayers.Event.stop(e);
                });
            }

            // sets the HTML provided into the nodelist element
            function setHTML(response){
                document.getElementById('nodelist').innerHTML = response.responseText;
            };

            // shows/hide the control panel
            function toggleControlPanel(event){
                var toolbar = document.getElementById("toolbar");
                if (toolbar.style.display == "none") {
                    toolbar.style.display = "block";
                }
                else {
                    toolbar.style.display = "none";
                }
                event.stopPropagation();
                map.updateSize()
            }

            // Tiling mode, can be 'tiled' or 'untiled'
            function setTileMode(tilingMode){
                if (tilingMode == 'tiled') {
                    untiled.setVisibility(false);
                    tiled.setVisibility(true);
                    map.setBaseLayer(tiled);
                }
                else {
                    untiled.setVisibility(true);
                    tiled.setVisibility(false);
                    map.setBaseLayer(untiled);
                }
            }

            // Transition effect, can be null or 'resize'
            function setTransitionMode(transitionEffect){
                if (transitionEffect === 'resize') {
                    tiled.transitionEffect = transitionEffect;
                    untiled.transitionEffect = transitionEffect;
                }
                else {
                    tiled.transitionEffect = null;
                    untiled.transitionEffect = null;
                }
            }

            // changes the current tile format
            function setImageFormat(mime){
                // we may be switching format on setup
                if(tiled == null)
                  return;

                tiled.mergeNewParams({
                    format: mime
                });
                untiled.mergeNewParams({
                    format: mime
                });
                /*
                var paletteSelector = document.getElementById('paletteSelector')
                if (mime == 'image/jpeg') {
                    paletteSelector.selectedIndex = 0;
                    setPalette('');
                    paletteSelector.disabled = true;
                }
                else {
                    paletteSelector.disabled = false;
                }
                */
            }

            // sets the chosen style
            function setStyle(style){
                // we may be switching style on setup
                if(tiled == null)
                  return;

                tiled.mergeNewParams({
                    styles: style
                });
                untiled.mergeNewParams({
                    styles: style
                });
            }

            // sets the chosen WMS version
            function setWMSVersion(wmsVersion){
                // we may be switching style on setup
                if(wmsVersion == null)
                  return;

                if(wmsVersion == "1.3.0") {
                   origin = map.maxExtent.bottom + ',' + map.maxExtent.left;
                } else {
                   origin = map.maxExtent.left + ',' + map.maxExtent.bottom;
                }

                tiled.mergeNewParams({
                    version: wmsVersion,
                    tilesOrigin : origin
                });
                untiled.mergeNewParams({
                    version: wmsVersion
                });
            }

            function setAntialiasMode(mode){
                tiled.mergeNewParams({
                    format_options: 'antialias:' + mode
                });
                untiled.mergeNewParams({
                    format_options: 'antialias:' + mode
                });
            }

            function setPalette(mode){
                if (mode == '') {
                    tiled.mergeNewParams({
                        palette: null
                    });
                    untiled.mergeNewParams({
                        palette: null
                    });
                }
                else {
                    tiled.mergeNewParams({
                        palette: mode
                    });
                    untiled.mergeNewParams({
                        palette: mode
                    });
                }
            }

            function setWidth(size){
                var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
                var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

                if (size == "auto") {
                    // reset back to the default value
                    mapDiv.style.width = null;
                    wrapper.style.width = null;
                }
                else {
                    mapDiv.style.width = size + "px";
                    wrapper.style.width = size + "px";
                }
                // notify OL that we changed the size of the map div
                map.updateSize();
            }

            function setHeight(size){
                var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');

                if (size == "auto") {
                    // reset back to the default value
                    mapDiv.style.height = null;
                }
                else {
                    mapDiv.style.height = size + "px";
                }
                // notify OL that we changed the size of the map div
                map.updateSize();
            }

            function updateFilter(){
                if(pureCoverage)
                  return;

                var filterType = document.getElementById('filterType').value;
                var filter = document.getElementById('filter').value;

                // by default, reset all filters
                var filterParams = {
                    filter: null,
                    cql_filter: null,
                    featureId: null
                };
                if (OpenLayers.String.trim(filter) != "") {
                    if (filterType == "cql") 
                        filterParams["cql_filter"] = filter;
                    if (filterType == "ogc") 
                        filterParams["filter"] = filter;
                    if (filterType == "fid") 
                        filterParams["featureId"] = filter;
                }
                // merge the new filter definitions
                mergeNewParams(filterParams);
            }

            function resetFilter() {
                if(pureCoverage)
                  return;

                document.getElementById('filter').value = "";
                updateFilter();
            }

            function mergeNewParams(params){
                tiled.mergeNewParams(params);
                untiled.mergeNewParams(params);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="init()">
        <div id="toolbar" style="display: none;">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a>WMS version:</a>
                    <select id="wmsVersionSelector" onchange="setWMSVersion(value)">
                        <option value="1.1.1">1.1.1</option>
                        <option value="1.3.0">1.3.0</option>
                    </select>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>Tiling:</a>
                    <select id="tilingModeSelector" onchange="setTileMode(value)">
                        <option value="untiled">Single tile</option>
                        <option value="tiled">Tiled</option>
                    </select>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>Transition effect:</a>
                    <select id="transitionEffectSelector" onchange="setTransitionMode(value)">
                        <option value="">None</option>
                        <option value="resize">Resize</option>
                    </select>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>Antialias:</a>
                    <select id="antialiasSelector" onchange="setAntialiasMode(value)">
                        <option value="full">Full</option>
                        <option value="text">Text only</option>
                        <option value="none">Disabled</option>
                    </select>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>Format:</a>
                    <select id="imageFormatSelector" onchange="setImageFormat(value)">
                        <option value="image/png">PNG 24bit</option>
                        <option value="image/png8">PNG 8bit</option>
                        <option value="image/gif">GIF</option>
                        <option id="jpeg" value="image/jpeg">JPEG</option>
                    </select>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>Styles:</a>
                    <select id="imageFormatSelector" onchange="setStyle(value)">
                        <option value="">Default</option>
                    </select>
                </li>
                <!-- Commented out for the moment, some code needs to be extended in 
                     order to list the available palettes
                <li>
                    <a>Palette:</a>
                    <select id="paletteSelector" onchange="setPalette(value)">
                        <option value="">None</option>
                        <option value="safe">Web safe</option>
                    </select>
                </li>
                -->
                <li>
                    <a>Width/Height:</a>
                    <select id="widthSelector" onchange="setWidth(value)">
                        <!--
                        These values come from a statistics of the viewable area given a certain screen area
                        (but have been adapted a litte, simplified numbers, added some resolutions for wide screen)
                        You can find them here: http://www.evolt.org/article/Real_World_Browser_Size_Stats_Part_II/20/2297/
                        --><option value="auto">Auto</option>
                        <option value="600">600</option>
                        <option value="750">750</option>
                        <option value="950">950</option>
                        <option value="1000">1000</option>
                        <option value="1200">1200</option>
                        <option value="1400">1400</option>
                        <option value="1600">1600</option>
                        <option value="1900">1900</option>
                    </select>
                    <select id="heigthSelector" onchange="setHeight(value)">
                        <option value="auto">Auto</option>
                        <option value="300">300</option>
                        <option value="400">400</option>
                        <option value="500">500</option>
                        <option value="600">600</option>
                        <option value="700">700</option>
                        <option value="800">800</option>
                        <option value="900">900</option>
                        <option value="1000">1000</option>
                    </select>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>Filter:</a>
                    <select id="filterType">
                        <option value="cql">CQL</option>
                        <option value="ogc">OGC</option>
                        <option value="fid">FeatureID</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="text" size="80" id="filter"/>
                    <img id="updateFilterButton" src="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/openlayers/img/east-mini.png" onClick="updateFilter()" title="Apply filter"/>
                    <img id="resetFilterButton" src="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/openlayers/img/cancel.png" onClick="resetFilter()" title="Reset filter"/>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="map">
            <img id="options" title="Toggle options toolbar" src="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/options.png"/>
        </div>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="location">location</div>
            <div id="scale">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="nodelist">
            <em>Click on the map to get feature info</em>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a LayerSwitcher control into the map.

```
var options = {
                controls: [new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher()],
                maxExtent: bounds,
                maxResolution: 74.78581333425757,
                projection: "EPSG:32644",
                units: 'm'
            };
```

Bear in mind that if you create a layer group, that will appear as an individual layer. You won't be able to switch the layers on and off individually.

Comment: Note to OP: The OpenLayers Build that comes with Geoserver is a `Lite` Build that contains limited classes. It is always advisable to download the complete OpenLayers Library and use that.